# How to get content to show in a block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a region called 'content top' and a block called 'sales' inside of that region. I then have a content type which lets a user upload an image and title. What i now need to do is take the content which was created and have it output in my sales block, so its basically an image getting displayed in the sales block.

Any ideas how to get my content to display in the block? the user may create another block in future called 'summer sales' and use the same content type to have an image displayed in that block, so hopefully there is a user friendly way of doing this.

I've done some Googling but haven't found anything, but I've a feeling it maybe something very simple in the end.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Laxman13, i did try that but never managed to get it working.

I found a solution in the end and i used the 'Nodes In Block' moudle http://drupal.org/project/nodesinblock

It did exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Create a view with a display type of "block"